# How to make smooth scroll effect but with scrolling stop at a specified height?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to make this scroll effect to an element having some `class/id`. What I don't get is to make the `scroll` stop at `20px` above this element. I've seen examples that do it with `document.getElementById()` . like this:

```
function scrollToJustAbove(element, margin=20) {
  let dims = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, dims.top - margin);
}
```

But, in my case I also need a `smooth transition` that is what I want (like my link in plnrk). How can I do it?

this is my code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3NX4FK5QrjiTwYgK5vwj?p=preview

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    const classElement = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
    if(classElement.length > 0){
      classElement[0].scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Does `scrollToJustAbove(classElement[0]);` work?

Comment: @Cat you can try my live code: https://plnkr.co/edit/3NX4FK5QrjiTwYgK5vwj?p=preview  and your answer not works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo#Syntax) instead of `element.scrollIntoView()`

The **scrollTo** method is **Polymorphic**. Apart from the params you already know, it instead also takes just an object (dictionary) in which you can specify the scroll behavior, like so:

```
<script>
 function scrollToJustAbove(element, margin=20) {
   let dims = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   window.scrollTo({
    top: dims.top - margin,
    behavior: 'smooth'
   });
 }

 setTimeout(() => {
   const classElement = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
   if(classElement.length > 0){
     scrollToJustAbove(classElement[0]);
   }
 }, 100);
</script>
```

**Working Example:** https://plnkr.co/edit/UevhAN4NmTCdw65dzuPe?p=preview